# hudson not checking out new svn revision with SCM polling even though it sees new revision

Tags: svn, hudson, timestamp, polling

i'm having an issue where hudson's SCM polling notices a change and sees the revision go up from #1 to #2. But in the output log when it does svn update, it's still checking out revision #1. d

one thing i noticed was that the times are off between my hudson and svn server. when i check in a file i look at my hudson server's time at its 7:04 but i look at the SVN log and it says 7:09 was the check in for revision #2. hudson will keep polling and seeing the revision change to #2 but it keeps downloading revision 1 and building that, until the hudson server time is 7:09 then it finally checks out revision 2 and builds.

how come hudson isn't able to just download the latest revision if it sees the revision # change? what does the timestamp have anything to do with it? do i just need to sync up the times on the 2 machines or is there any other option (besides subversion post comit hook, since i want to still do polling?)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a legacy issue, Hudson doesn't use HEAD because that causes problems on Matrix builds, see [JENKINS-1241](http://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-1241). Sync the times, and you'll be good to go.